# Ruby CSV does not understand \r\n as row end

Tags: ruby, csv

I use an iPhone app that periodically emails me a log in CSV format. I have a ruby script that sums the data in that log with older logs. Recently the app developer released an update that, for some unknown reason, added a carriage return to the end of each line, causing my script to fail. According to the docs, `:row_end` by default should be `:auto`, which should accept either `\r\n` or `\n` (in 1.9.2). I've tried using Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2 and FasterCSV with 1.8.7. I get various error messages with these different tries, including

- `CSV::IllegalFormatError`
- Unquoted fields do not allow `\r` or `\n` (line 1) (`FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError`)
- can't dup `NilClass` (TypeError)

in 1.9.2. (The `\r` is not in a field, it's the end of the line!) The data formerly looked like this:

```
03-12-2012 07:59,120.0,
03-11-2012 08:27,120.0,
03-10-2012 07:57,120.0,
```

Now it looks like this:

```
03-12-2012 07:59,120.0,^M
03-11-2012 08:27,120.0,^M
03-10-2012 07:57,120.0,^M
```

Thinking that CSV may be thinking the `^M` is in the last field, I tried adding another comma:

```
03-12-2012 07:59,120.0,,^M
```

to no avail.

The only thing I can imagine is that CSV requires all fields to be in double quotes?
I can think of various workarounds, such as reading the file in first, chomping the ends, then processing the array with CSV, but first I want to find out what I'm doing wrong. It seems like it should work.

By the way my code is simply:

```
CSV.foreach(File.join($import_dir, file)) do |record|
```

and I've tried setting `:row_end => "\r\n"` to no avail.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me in 1.9.3:

```
mark@ubuntu:~$ irb
1.9.3p0 :001 > require 'csv'
 => true
1.9.3p0 :002 > CSV.foreach("rn.csv") do |row|
1.9.3p0 :003 >   p row
1.9.3p0 :004 > end
["1","2","3","4","5"]
["6","7","8","9","10"]
```

And the file does indeed have carriage returns in it:

```
mark@ubuntu:~$ od -a rn.csv
0000000   1   ,   2   ,   3   ,   4   ,   5  cr  nl   6   ,   7   ,   8
0000020   ,   9   ,   1   0  cr  nl
0000027
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Hadn't thought of looking at the file with od. Turns out the line ends in \r\r\n.

Answer (score 8):

Because CSV needs to read/parse the entire file when `row_end` is automatic, I needed to do the following to prevent formatting and encoding exceptions.

- Decode the file through `File.read`
- Remove those pesky carriage returns (could be one or more)
- Parse the cleansed file as CSV

```ruby
file = File.read(temp_file.path, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1:UTF-8')
file = file.tr("\r", '')

CSV.parse(file, headers: true) do |row|
  # do all the things
end
```

Note: I am using version Ruby 2.1.3 for a Rails 4 application.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the `row_end` to

```
"\r\n"
```

This is different to '\r\n': single quoted strings only allow you to escape ' and \, any thing else is treated as a literal \, ie

```
'\r' == "\\r"
```

Is true

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned trying `:row_end => '\r\n'`. Single quotes treat (most instances of) backslashes as regular backslash characters; try `:row_end => "\r\n"`, with double quotes.

Comment: My mistake. I did try that. Same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The lines of the file actually end with \r\r\n, not \r\n
This is embarrassing, I should have checked the file in more detail. I 
was assuming that the end of line was \n, since I'm on a Unix box.
But when Emacs opened the file it automatically went into "DOS" mode so it displayed \r\n as a new line and only displayed the extra \r as "^M"

Comment: This was the case for me. Vim showed the extra `\r` as `^M` and the lines actually ended in `\r\r\n`. Watch out people.